# Birt add line to the bottom of the last page

Tags: birt

I have a BIRT 232 report that I need to add a line to the bottom of the last page. I can add a footer. But that adds the line right after the data. I need the line to be at the bottom of the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I did find a solution. It was sneaky. I'll see if I can dig it up. Keep working on it, there is a solution.

Comment: can you post your solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Do you only need the line last page or at the bottom of every page? If the latter would work add the line to the masterpage. If you don't want the line on every page just add the following script in the onRender function of the line element in the masterpage.

```
if(pageNumber < totalPage){
    this.getStyle().display ="none"
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It seems that `pageNumber` is always equal to `totalPage`. Am I missing something?